# Position a block at the top of <head>

Tags: layout, head

I'm using the following to add  tags to my  :

```
  <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
       <block  class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="head.font" template="Magento_Theme::html/head_font.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

The issue is I want them to load first, not last. Is there a way to position block at the top of  ?

Comment: Use  before="-" in your block tag

Answer (score 0):

Please do as below then this block displays before all other elements in its parent node.

**From:**

```
 <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
       <block  class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="head.font" template="Magento_Theme::html/head_font.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

**To:**

```
 <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
       <block  class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="head.font" template="Magento_Theme::html/head_font.phtml" before="-" />
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to have any effect